# Linked List Implementation in C#

Tags: c#, linked-list

I am creating linked list in c#, I have been using a website to learn from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104980/Linked-List-Implementation-in-Csharp

This site has code that i try and I have issues with a problem. The code i am using is

```
public class Node
{
    public Node Next;
    public object Value;
}
public class LinkedList
{
    private Node head;
    private Node current;//This will have latest node
    public int Count;
}

public LinkedList()
{
    head = new Node();
    current = head;
}

public void AddAtLast(object data)
{
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.Value = data;
    current.Next = newNode;
    current = newNode;
    Count++;
}

public void AddAtStart(object data)
{
    Node newNode = new Node() { Value = data};
    newNode.Next = head.Next;//new node will have reference of head's next reference
    head.Next = newNode;//and now head will refer to new node
    Count++;
}
```

The code copied from website, so should be no error. But my problem is, when i add items to the start of the list with AddAtStart and then i add at end of list with AddAtLast, AddAtLast deletes all the nodes i had added before and only now stores the new AddAtLast entry. I maby think this could be because of current. I think that current is thinking it is the head and not the last node, so when i add at end it adds at start and removes all. Could this be the cause of my problems.

If I only use AddAtStart it all works good, all nodes get added, i can have many nodes, but just when AddAtLast is used, everything goes away

EDIT i forgot my code was differet from site my apologies. I shall edit with my code I am using

```
public class LinkedList
{
    private Node head;
    private Node current;//This will have latest node
    public int Count;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        head = new Node();
        current = head;
    }

    public void PrintAllNodes()
    { 
        //Traverse from head
        Console.Write("Head ->");
        Node curr = head;
        while (curr.Next != null)
        {
            curr = curr.Next;
            Console.Write(curr.Value);
            Console.Write("->");
        }
        Console.Write("NULL");
    }

    public void AddAtStart(object data)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node() { Value = data};
        newNode.Next = head.Next;//new node will have reference of head's next reference
        head.Next = newNode;//and now head will refer to new node
        Count++;
    }

    public void AddAtLast(object data)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.Value = data;
        current.Next = newNode;
        current = newNode;
        Count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added indentation to your code. I assume because you say it compiles and runs that you've made a mistake copying it here and the constructor for the `LinkedList` class as well as the `AddAtLast()` and `AddAtStart()` methods are meant to be in the `LinkedList` class?

Comment: yes it was mistake, i added the correct code as edit now

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused because the structure of your class `LinkedList` need to be fixed. You will have to move its constructor and methods into its declaration as below:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node Next;
    public object Value;
}

public class LinkedList
{
    private Node head;
    private Node current;//This will have latest node
    public int Count;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        head = new Node();
        current = head;
    }

    public void AddAtLast(object data)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.Value = data;
        current.Next = newNode;
        current = newNode;
        Count++;
    }

    public void AddAtStart(object data)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node() { Value = data };
        newNode.Next = head.Next; //new node will have reference of head's next reference
        head.Next = newNode; //and now head will refer to new node
        Count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I forgot, i apologies I forgot I actually have it the way you said. I copied from site rather than my code to all my comments would not be copied over. But I have everything within the linkedlist class and i am getting my issue. My class linkedList is not public though, maby that issue. I will try that

Answer (score 0):

Your `current` node is set to `head` in the constructor and then only updated in `AddAtLast()`.
What is happening is when you add nodes with `AddAtStart()` current doesn't change and always points to `head` so when you call `AddAtLast()` it makes `head.Next` point to the `newNode` and then makes current the new node. You lose all the nodes that `head` used to point to.

To add to the end of a linked list, you have to traverse the list until you come to a node where `node.next == null` (i.e. the last node) then add the node there. Alternatively, create a field `Node Last` and update it to always point to the last node whenever you add to the end of the list. Then you can just append new nodes to `Last`.

The following will update current so it points to the last node then add a node to the end.

```
public void AddAtLast (object data) {
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.Value = data;
    while (_current.Next != null) {
        current = current.Next; // Traverse current until it points to the last node
    }
    current.Next = newNode;
    current = newNode;
    Count++;
}
```

Comment: yes i thought current = head was maby the problem. Thank you for helping, I can fix it from here i hope. Thank you